# PHP Imagick - "-quantize transparent" equivalent

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Is there a PHP Imagick equivalent for `-quantize transparent` ???

[-quantize transparent usage example](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#color_trans) note: seach for '-quantize transparent' within page

Comment: did you look at this page?...http://php.net/manual/en/gmagick.quantizeimage.php

Comment: @Dinesh        Gmagick is a different api extension...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Quantize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.quantizeimage.php) is supported by PHP's Imagick extension; however, little documentation has been authored. Luckily, the example from "[Color Quantization and Transparency](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#color_trans)" is straightforward.

```bash
convert alpha_gradient.png -quantize transparent \
    +dither  -colors 15   alpha_colors_15qt.png
```

From this example, we can determine the 5 arguments needed by `Imagick::quantizeImage()`.

- Number of colors = 15 (*-colors 15*)
- Colorspace = transparent
- Tree depth = 0 (*undefined*)
- Dither = False (*+dither*)
- Messure errors = False

```php
<?php

$wand = new Imagick("alpha_gradient.png");
$wand->quantizeImage(15,Imagick::COLORSPACE_TRANSPARENT,0,false,false);
$wand->writeImage("alpha_colors_15qt.png");
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately if I use `Imagick::COLORSPACE_TRANSPARENT` all transparency/alpha are translated to black. IMagick, for some reason, will not ignore alpha/transparency unless a color palette of above `256` colors is specified with `Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB`. So weird. `quantizeImage(257, Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB, 0, false, false )` = preserved transparency. `quantizeImage(256, Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB, 0, false, false )` = transparency translated to black.

Comment: Hmm. I'm unable to reproduce/experience this issue (using ImageMagick 6.8.0-4 on OS X 10.8.2). It sounds like PHP's Imagick extension is working fine, but the underlining ImageMagick install might be the cause of the issue. Does repeating the same command(s) with `convert` method generate the same images?

Comment: `exec('convert $file -quantize rgb +dither -colors 257 $file_new');` will preserve transparency. Anything less then `257` or specifying `transparent` and not `rgb` will translate all transparency to black. I think it might have to do with my ImageMagick install version, 6.6.4. I'm going to install a newer version and test again... Ps. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Thank You So Much!!! Your explanation was more then great. Btw, the trouble I was running into was with my version of IM.