# Save PNG as PNG-8 with Floyd-Steinberg 2 dithering like GIMP in PHP

Tags: php, image, gimp, png-8

In GIMP I can save an image for Web with these properties:

[image]

- PNG-8
- 256 colors palette
- Dither: Floyd-Steinberg / Floyd-Steinberg 2 / positioned

With these options I can reduce upto about 70% of the size of the image file without evident quality loss.

How can I get the same result with PHP?

The resulting image must preserve transparency.

I know almost nothing about image compression, encoding, palette, etc.

**Edit:** I posted a new question with a PHP script to do that, so I'll close this question or I'll answer it.

[PHP wrong result for imagetruecolortopalette with PNG with transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57992171)

Comment: You might want to mention that you can't install libraries as you said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57972413/lossy-compression-of-png-in-php-without-installing-anything-on-the-server). And you might just want to [implement the dithering yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Steinberg_dithering), it's not that complicated.

Comment: In a comment on the other question, you said, _“I need the best quality preservation, because they are high-resolution photos.”_ – and now we’re gonna pretend an 8-bit palette image would actually satisfy those requirements? You must either be kidding, or you are doing a bad job at describing what you actually need in the first place. (Plus you kinda brought that as a counter-argument over there, when someone originally suggested you go with a palette-based format …)

Comment: @04FS By doing that GIMP preserves the visible quality I need. English isn't my mother language, so I may bad wrote something. But this is a different, but similar, question: here I'm asking specifically for the replication of what GIMP can do.

Comment: @Tox here I do not preclude the option to install some library (in the localhost)

Comment: See my earlier comment, just implement the dithering yourself and go with PHP's `image*` functions, or [look here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagetruecolortopalette.php).

Comment: Maybe with PHP Imagick... https://stackoverflow.com/a/13335428/2836621

Comment: @Tox you says "it's not that complicated" but it sound to me: learn a lot before being able to reproduce it with PHP in an efficient way :)

Comment: [Here's](https://gist.github.com/Toxyl/107b56499cbfe5a7a08710070a270251) an  implementation of dithering with different algorithms. It's ActionScript 3, I'll leave it up to you to translate it to PHP. ;)

Comment: thanks, I'll study it :)

Comment: Guys, please see my edit.